# Unity Error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, I'm getting this error from Unity engine and I'm unsure how to fix it. I've been trying to find a solution, but I'm coming to nothing. I'm a beginner to scripting, that being I've never scripted before. My script looks something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        var movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        var rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        rigidbody.velocity = movement * speed;

        object boundary = null;
        rigidbody.position = new Vector3
            (
             Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
            );

    }
}
```

May I get some help on how to fix this? It's saying there are problems with my xMin, xMax, zMin, and zMax. This is supposed to be for a bullet hell and keeps the player from going out of bounds, but it cannot work if I can't set boundaries.
I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJHRkdRq4BQ
(This is all scripted in C#)

May I even get another good tutorial if that's any help?

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383961.aspx):

> 'type' does not contain a definition for 'member' and no extension
>   method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'type' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). This
>   error occurs when you try to call a method or access a class member
>   that does not exist.

Your problem is here:

```
object boundary = null;
rigidbody.position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
    );
```

The problem is that `boundary` is of type `object`, and `object` doesn't contain a definition for `xMin`, nor `xMax`, etc. For this to work, `boundary`needs to be of type `Boundary`, like this:

```
Boundary boundary = null;
rigidbody.position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
    );
```

However, this will in turn give you a `NullReferenceException`, since you are trying to use properties from an object that wasn't ever created. You could do something like this to fix that:

```
Boundary boundary = new Boundary
{
    xMin = 134.0f;
    xMax = 146.0f;
    zMin = 112.0f;
    zMax = 153.0f;
}; // assign some values otherwise it will all default to 0.0f
rigidbody.position = new Vector3
    (
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        0.0f,
        Mathf.Clamp (rigidbody.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
    );
```